# Cordova admob-pro, some ads freeze, on iPhone 6 (not iPhone5)

Tags: cordova, admob, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

Ive been using admob-pro for some of my apps and its all been working fine. Today however, some ads (not video) just freeze! One is not able to close them nor to click anywhere in the ad to get redirected. Very confusing. See below for one of these ads. I cant see any general issues reported in Admob nor at the plugin admob-pro. All worked fine previously and video ads are still showing. Does anyone know if there are any changes to admob or in the admob-pro plugin since recently (last few days) or has anyone seen this happen before? Also, this seems to happen on my iPhone 6 but not on an iPhone 5.

I know Im not shwoing any code here but as I said, its all been working well but now, not so much so Im generally looking for any experience from either Admob or Admob-pro cordova plugin just changing their APIs.

[image: Sample ad that does not close]

UPDATE:
Sometimes, I see another "x" show up in the top left corner but it disappears very quickly, before I get a chance to click it. Clicking where it showed up after it disappears does noting.

Has really no one experienced or seen this?

Comment: Have you tried with other plugins? For me this one is working fine: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/

Comment: @C.Miller Thanks. No, Ive not tried this one. Would really prefer not to redo this for all apps and release all again if its something "small".